# I need to Cut and Mix Strings

Tags: lua, roblox

i would like to know how i could cut and mix strings, im making a player fusion script for my game, but i dont know how i can make their name be togheter, like, if player 1 name is LordNoob and player 2 name is Keyboard then it would mix their names to one like Lordoard or KeyNoob something like that.

Ive searching a few things on the roblox wiki but i didnt found nothing, i saw string patterns but i dont know if it would help me.

If anyone could tell me what i could do it would be a cool help. thank you.

Comment: How would you know that LordNoob can be split between `d` and `N`? Would you rely on `N` being capitalized inside the keyword? Then Keyboard needs to be written as `KeyBoard`. Or would you rely on sections of the keyword to be present in some dictionary? In this case `key`, `noob`, `lord`, and `board` need to be there. Unless you can come up with one of these or similar options, you are left with some random splits that are likely to produce `Loard` and `KeybordNoob`.

Comment: This sounds more like a request than a question about a problem you're having.  Please refer to [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried making a function for you which works okay, having the flaws that Paul mentioned

```
function mixStrings(string1,string2)
return string.upper(string.sub(string1,1,1)) .. string.lower( string.sub( string.sub(string1,1,math.floor(string.len(string1)/2)) ,2,string.len(string.sub(string1,1,math.floor(string.len(string1)/2)))) .. string.sub(string2,math.ceil(string.len(string2)/2),string.len(string2)) )
end

print(mixStrings("Keyboard","Calculator"))
print(mixStrings("Narwhal","Shark"))
print(mixStrings("America","Europe"))
print(mixStrings("Spoon","Fork"))
```

Running the above script resulted in the following when I tested it:

```
Keybulator
Narark
Amerope
Spork
```

(Btw the function will always make a string with a capitalized first letter and the rest will be lowercase, so it probably won't be useful if you're aiming to make something like KeyNoob)

Comment: No problem, Thank you!